# LWJGL Mouse not responding to Cocoa Simulated Mouse Event

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, lwjgl

I have some Java code using LWJGL:

```
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse; 
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
...
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(200, 200));
Display.create();
Mouse.create();
Mouse.setGrabbed(true);
while (true) 
{
    Display.update();
    System.out.println("Data: d("+ Mouse.getDX() + "," + Mouse.getDY() + ") p(" + Mouse.getX() + "," + Mouse.getY() + ")");
    Thread.sleep(1000/20);
}
```

It works fine when I physically move my mouse around, however when I use a Cocoa application to simulate moving the mouse:

- `getDX()` and `getDY()` return 0
- `getX()` and `getY()` return the previous value (as if the mouse hasn't moved)

The code I'm using to move the mouse is this:

```
PostMouseEvent(0, kCGEventMouseMoved, mouseLocation);
...
void PostMouseEvent(CGMouseButton button, CGEventType type, const CGPoint point)
{    
    CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(point);
    CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, type, point, button);
    CGEventSetType(theEvent, type);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);
    CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(1);
    CFRelease(theEvent);
}
```

which works a charm in just about all other applications (including mouseover events).

How can I modify my Objective-C so that LWJGL responds correctly to mouse events?

Cheers

**Additional Information:**

After moving the mouse physically and stopping, I get this (for example) in the log:

```
Data: d(0,0) p(379,-748)
Data: d(0,0) p(379,-748)
Data: d(0,0) p(379,-748)
Data: d(0,0) p(379,-748)
Data: d(0,0) p(379,-748)
Data: d(0,0) p(379,-748)
```

The above continues to show when I let my Cocoa application move the mouse

Then when I move the mouse again the values jump to:

```
Data: d(163,123) p(542,-625)     //this seems like a huge change!
Data: d(8,7) p(550,-618)         //normal
Data: d(0,0) p(550,-618)         //normal
Data: d(48,36) p(598,-582)       //etc
```

it seems as if the mouse teleported?

Edit: when using `java.awt.Robot` to move the mouse LWJGL responds as anticipated.

Comment: I don't see that the problem is? ... or maybe I just don't understand your questions?

Comment: LWJGL simply doesn't respond to simulated mouse events - it's as if the mouse isn't moving

Comment: Yes it does, all the `getDX()` and `getDY()` values are correct.

Comment: No... They should be changing as the mouse moves, however they don't. Sorry, I'm not sure how to explain it

Comment: Then show some logging, where it fails! Because the two log prints you already have they are correct.

Comment: The first log occurs when I move the mouse programmatically - the integers should be changing as the mouse moves!

Comment: Ohh now I get it, well did you try moving the mouse through Java, seeing if that makes any difference?

Comment: `java.awt.Robot` appears to work as expected! Thanks for your help! Do you think I'll have to make my Cocoa application call a Java one for every mouse movement?

Comment: How you accomplish it is up to you, though as you can see the problem lies within the Cocoa mouse thingy (I don't know what the Cocoa thing is so yea).

Comment: Did you find another way than using Java? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @idmean unfortunately no, I ended up having to write the movement handling directly in the Java :( - would still be interested in a solution though hahahah

Comment: @Jugale I found out that the problem is Cocoa itself! No Cocoa app responds to mouse moves, made by `CGEventPost`. And since [LWJGL is using Cocoa](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/native/macosx/org_lwjgl_opengl_Display.m#L458) it does not respond...

Comment: @idmean that's interesting! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first assumption that no Cocoa app responds to mouse moves made by `CGEventPost` was wrong. The real problem is:

If you move the mouse with `CGEventPost` and `CGEventCreateMouseEvent`, the event does not have a `deltaX` and a `deltaY` value. And a lot of applications seem to depend on them (as my destination application (Minecraft) does, which receives these values from LWJGL).

You have to manually compute these values and set them on the event.

Example code right from my project:

```
CGEventRef pointGetEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
CGPoint point = CGEventGetLocation(pointGetEvent);
CFRelease(pointGetEvent);

if(test(SNES_Y)){
    CGPoint oldPoint = point;
    if(test(SNES_LEFT)){
        point = CGPointMake(point.x - MOUSE_STEP, point.y);
    }
    if(test(SNES_RIGHT)){
        point = CGPointMake(point.x + MOUSE_STEP, point.y);
    }
    if(test(SNES_DOWN)){
        point = CGPointMake(point.x, point.y + MOUSE_STEP);
    }
    if(test(SNES_UP)){
        point = CGPointMake(point.x, point.y - MOUSE_STEP);
    }

    if(oldPoint.x != point.x || oldPoint.y != point.y){
        CGEventRef move1 = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved, point, kCGMouseButtonLeft);
        CGEventSetDoubleValueField(move1, kCGMouseEventDeltaX, point.x - oldPoint.x);
        CGEventSetDoubleValueField(move1, kCGMouseEventDeltaY, point.y - oldPoint.y);
        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, move1);
        CFRelease(move1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @idmean - I too was working with Minecraft, and my solution was to mod it